# Confusion about Rudin Submodule

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

[image]

Here $V_1, V_2$ are multiplication operator by coordinate functions. The above Theorem is a result obtained by V. Madrekar in 1988.

In the article "A brief survey of operator theory on $H^2(\mathbb D^2)$'' by R. Yang, 2018, the author mentioned an example constructed by W. Rudin in "Function Theory on Polydiscs" as follows:

Consider $M=[z-w]$, a closed subspace of $H^2(\mathbb D^2)$ generates by the function $f(z,w)=z-w$, invariant under the operator $T_z,T_w$, multiplication by coordinate functions $z$ and $w$, then there does not exists any inner function $q$ such that $M=q.H^2(\mathbb D^2)$.

From Mandrekar's theorem, it is clear that the pair $(T_z, T_w)$ cannot be doubly commuting on $M$. I am confused about how to find such $f\in M=[z-w]$ which violates the condition of doubly commuting property. I have tried many functions, but could not find the contradiction. Any help regarding this will be beneficial. Thanks in advance.